# navigation drawer with navigation component back arrow not show when drawer is open

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

I implemented a NavigationDrawer with NavigationComponent, but when I open my menu via the hamburger icon or swipe gesture, the icon don't change to the back arrow and also when I click on the icon, with drawer open, the drawer dosen't close. This problem occur when I added AppBarConfiguration to my NavigationDrawer to display the hamburger icon in [top-level-destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration), otherwise the back arrow. Before it works fine, but in my sub screens the hamburger icon was also shown, so I wanted to get rid of it.

setup code:

```
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    int[] topLevelDestinations = new int[]{R.id.mapFragment, R.id.petManagementFragment, R.id.accountManagementFragment, R.id.mailSupportFragment, R.id.aboutFragment};
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            topLevelDestinations).setOpenableLayout(getDrawerLayout()).build();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(getToolbar(), navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(getNavigationView(), navController);

    getNavigationView().setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this);
```

Comment: Are you using `setSupportActionBar()` with your `getToolbar()`?

Comment: Yes I do this in my onCreate() method